# Very low brightness in setup

Tags: display, brightness, setup

My screen is in very low brightness during setup, and can barley see using a torch. Im new to ubuntu and using 13.04 so please make it simple thanks.

Laptop: Acer Aspire 5336
Model: PEW72
Shared graphics
Intel celeron CPU

Thanx 
Really need help as my windows is stuffed up.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the notebook from the AC Power while booting up. I had the same issue with an old version and that worked. After you log in fully you can plug-in the power again.

It has to do with Acer's ACPI settings. The other way is to add acpi_osi=Linux to boot options, with the e grub command.